# how to make time in the form HH MM and be able to work with it? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make it so that instead of doing something like:

```
if (hrs >= 8 && hrs <= 9.3167) {
    do stuff;
}
```

do:

```
if (time >= 8:00 && time <= 9:19) {
    do stuff;
}
```

I have tried this:

```
var date = new Date;
var hh = date.getHours();
var mm = date.getMinutes();

if (hh < 10) {hh = "0"+hh;}
if (mm < 10) {mm = "0"+mm;}

var t = hh+":"+mm;
```

which then gets you:

```
if (t >= "08:00" && t <= "9:19") {
    do stuff;
}
```

But it outputs the time as a string, and  it doesn't work properly in the rest of my code.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot work with "hh:mm" times, you need to use `Date` objects. Formatting it like hh:mm or any other format only serves for output (e.g. showing it on the console or the webpage) but not for programming.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var now = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var checkTime = function() {
  var today = weekday[now.getDay()];
  var timeDiv = document.getElementById('timeDiv');
  var dayOfWeek = now.getDay();
  var hour = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();

  //add AM or PM
  var suffix = hour >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";

  // add 0 to one digit minutes
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes
  };

  if ((dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 6) && hour >= 13 && hour <= 23) {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
    timeDiv.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + ' - we\'re open!';
    timeDiv.className = 'open';
  } 
  
  else if ((dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 4 || dayOfWeek == 5) && hour >= 16 && hour <= 23) {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1);
    timeDiv.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + ' - we\'re open!';
    timeDiv.className = 'open';
  } 
  
  else {
    if (hour == 0 || hour > 12) {
      hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
    }
    timeDiv.innerHTML = 'It\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + ' - we\'re closed!';
    timeDiv.className = 'closed';
  }
};

var currentDay = weekday[now.getDay()];
var currentDayID = "#" + currentDay; //gets todays weekday and turns it into id
$(currentDayID).toggleClass("today"); //hightlights today in the view hours modal popup

setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
checkTime();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#main {
  background: url(http://files.kaboompics.com/upload/823_min.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

#logo {
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 400px;
}

#logo img {
  width: 100%;
}

#darkBack {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#timeDiv {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 325px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.open {
  color: #27ae60;
  border: 2px solid #27ae60;
}

.closed {
  color: rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.85);
  border: 2px solid rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.8);
}

.viewOpen {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 2px solid rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.7);
  max-width: 170px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.8);
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px -8px #adadad;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.viewOpen i {
  color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.8);
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  #timeDiv {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 601px) {
  #timeDiv {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
}

.dateTime {
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.day {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.time {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right
}

.today {
  color: rgb(200, 85, 39);
  font-weight: 600;
}

@media all and (max-height: 420px) {
  #timeDiv, .viewOpen {
    top: 60%;
  }
}
/* view hours modal */

@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(173, 173, 173, 0.5);
  display: none;
}

#modal-state {
  display: none;
}

#modal-state:checked + .modal-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fade-in .4s;
  display: block;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 25px;
  background: #fff;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 400px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}



.modal h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dce0d8;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@media all and (max-width: 470px) {
  .modal {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .modal h2{
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

#modal-state:checked + .modal-overlay .modal {
  top: 20%;
}

.modal-overlay-close {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.button-close {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background: #464646;
  padding: 0px 7px;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="darkBack"></div>
  <div id="logo"><img src="http://401creative.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Griddle_Logo.png" /></div>

  <div id="timeDiv"></div>
  <label class="viewOpen" for="modal-state">View Hours&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="modal-state" id="modal-state">
  <div class="modal-overlay">
    <label for="modal-state" class="modal-overlay-close"></label>
    <div class="modal">
      <label class="button-close" for="modal-state"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></label>
      <h2>We're Open At These Times</h2>
      <div id="Wednesday" class="dateTime">
        <div class="day">Wednesday</div>
        <div class="time">4pm - 12am</div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="Thursday" class="dateTime">
        <div class="day">Thursday</div>
        <div class="time">4pm - 12am</div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="Friday" class="dateTime">
        <div class="day">Friday</div>
        <div class="time">4pm - 12am</div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="Saturday" class="dateTime">
        <div class="day">Saturday</div>
        <div class="time">1pm - 12am</div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="Sunday" class="dateTime">
        <div class="day">Sunday</div>
        <div class="time">1pm - 12am</div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="Monday" class="dateTime">
        <div class="day">Monday</div>
        <div class="time">Closed</div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="Tuesday" class="dateTime">
        <div class="day">Tuesday</div>
        <div class="time">Closed</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```